# JSCH - Invalid private key -working in actual server

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

We are trying to use JSCH to download the file from a remote server. The SFTP key exchange is already set up between the two servers when we try

```
SFP username@hostname
```

it connects successfully without asking for any password.
But in java code when we try connecting using JSCH getting invalid private key exception.

```
ERROR com.crer.log.debug - com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey:
```

the code I have done is something like below

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
            String privateKey = location of the private key on client server
            jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
            session = jsch.getSession(stpUser, sftpHost, sftpPort);
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
```

**Edit:**

The JSCH version im using is 0.1.54

The private key begins like

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY ----
Subject: username
Comment: "2048-bit rsa, username@host, Tue Dec 13 2016 19:25:22 \
-0500"
```

I even tried converting the private key to openssh format but getting some exception

```
ssh-keygen -i -f id_rsa_2048_a > id_rsa_2048_a_openssh
Private key -f is unreadable: Failed to open `-f': No such file or directory / Failed to read file `-f'.
Error: Cannot determine the type of the key.
```

if i remove the -f from the command it works but I believe the file is not properly converted as if i use that file i get the same exception.

Any help here will be very helpful . Not sure whats going wrong.

Comment: Please post the entire exception, not just the first line.

Comment: What's your private key file like? Show us its header.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to indicate the version of JSCH that you are using.

Comment: @Kenster  added the same.

Comment: Try to convert the file using PuTTYgen.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i dont have putty also we use tectia.

Comment: So download it, it's free.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl so JSch doesnt support ssh tectia keys? any other library that supports ssh tectia keys?

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this in Jenkins ssh plugin which also use JSCH.

JSCH only accept the old PEM format private key. It can be generate as follow:

```sh
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa
```

The `-m PEM` instruct ssh-keygen to output in PEM format which can be accepted by JCSH.